# Capturing Memory / IO counters for ASP.NET Web Applications in IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, asp.net, perfmon

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 (Web API) web application hosted in IIS on Windows Server 2008 R2. This web application is hosted in it's own application pool using the Integrated pipeline.

I am trying to use Performance Monitor to capture the amount of memory and IO pressure of the application.

Specifically:

- How much memory (managed or otherwise) is the application consuming?
- How much IO work (request data in / response data out - not writing to disk) is the application performing at any given second?

I intend to capture these metrics so that I can gauge performance benefits of various enhancements we have to a specific part of our system.

*I am **not** interested in requests per second style load testing - this will be handled separately.*

**Problem:** I am struggling to identify the correct performance counters to use to capture the above metrics.

There are many different counters that relate to memory usage and all of the ones I have tried do not seem change... even when I upload a 1GB file to my application.

For IO pressure I am using IO Read / Write (sec) counters under the Process object... but if I'm honest I'm only guessing.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Is Perfmon the right tool for the job?